# How to most concisely initialize std::map using an initializer list that includes a constructor call for the mapped_type

Tags: c++, c++17

The vector constructor calls in the statement below construct vectors with 50 elements of identical values in each vector as values in the sviMap. The statement repeats `vector<int>` three times. Is there a more concise way to achieve this overall initialization of the sviMap where `vector<int>` appears only once in the statement?

`map<string, vector<int>> sviMap { {"Leo", vector<int>(50, 101)} , {"Brad", vector<int>(50, 201)} };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, **no**. You need to have template specialization and two instances of the vector.

But if you need to have "this text once", this workaround could work for you:

```
using vi = vector<int>;
map<string, vi> sviMap{ {"Leo", vi(50, 101)} , {"Brad", vi(50, 201)} };
```

Formally, this is not "the statement", but two statements, but the vector appears only once. If your goal is to have one point for changes, this could work.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to correct my mistake, so here's another solution.
And this one will result in vectors of the correct length.
I just used inheritance to create a vector type with a constructor that has the desired behavior, so you can then use initializer lists without extra specifics

```
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename type_t>
class my_vector :
    public std::vector<type_t>
{
public:
    my_vector() = default;
    my_vector(const size_t size, const type_t value) :
        std::vector<type_t>(size, value)
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, my_vector<int>> sviMap{ { "Leo", {50, 101}}, { "Brad", {50, 201}} };
    auto vec = sviMap["Leo"];
    auto value = vec[23];
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround with one reservation, your new type will have a little bit different constructor behavior (exactly you wanted to get) and this could be a trap if somebody(you) will use it later. I personally would avoid such "slight differences". Anyway, nice one.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I hear you, yes it was quick and dirty ;)
If you want a more clean looking solution this is one : https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/HngqzzCKE. Shall I add that one here too?

Comment: @Papijn, it is up to you. Not my question, not my right to make such decisions. )  The only thing I would do, is to convert it to template so that it could be done in compile-time thus making sure that assignment inside the loop is optimized out by compiler. Nice approach, I missed it, frankly.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this, just use nested initializers

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> sviMap
    { 
        {"Leo", {50, 101}}, 
        {"Brad", {50, 201}} 
    };

    auto vec = sviMap["Leo"];
}
```

Comment: there is a difference between the vector<int>(50, 101) which initializes first 50 elements with 101 value and {50, 101} which in your case just initialize array with two elements: 50 and 101. So, your code just "doing another thing".